# Finding a single integer in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to solve an algorithm question. I need to find a single integer in an array

e.g
{1,1,5,5,5,3,2,2}

output should 3 because that's the only single integer there.

So far, I created an algorithm where first I sort the array and then check whether i-1 and i+1 elements are equal and if not it means I've got the single one.

The issue is; for short input it's working fine but for long inputs I receive time-outs (it takes too long to compute so my answer is not validated).

Could you give me any tips for improving the algorithm

```
static int lonelyinteger(int[] a) {

    Arrays.sort(a);

    if (a.length == 1)
        return a[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {

        if (i == 0) {
            if (a[i + 1] != a[i])
                return a[i];
        } else if (i == a.length - 1) {
            if (a[i] != a[i - 1])
                return a[i];
        } else {
            if (a[i - 1] != a[i] && a[i + 1] != a[i])
                return a[i];
        }  
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Give an example of an input that causes this to happen.

Comment: what exact exception are you getting? (with stack)

Comment: You don't need to sort the array. Iterate through it once, and construct a map of every number you see, and the numbers of times you've seen it. Then just print the numbers with counter == 1.

Comment: What do you mean by **time-out**?

Comment: I'm not getting any exception. for inputs really long (a million integers), it takes too much to compute and my answer is not validated.

Comment: The map idea works, but keep in mind that it about triples the memory needed compared to an in-place sort (depending on how many single vs multiple entries there are).  For small N that does not matter, but for very large N relative to available memory it would.

Comment: Do you need to identify *all* "singleton" integers (if more than one is present), or just the first one? Or do we assume only one will exist?

Comment: @DavidW,  one integer will be certainly singleton others vary. and yes only one singleton.

Comment: Can you give us more information? what is the number range? how many numbers in the array?

Comment: "time-outs (it takes too long to compute [...])" How long *can* it take?

Comment: Why check i-1 and i+1 ? You can increase your iterator by 2. And check only i and i+1

Comment: cf. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78483/hacker-rank-lonely-integer (It may also be from a similar coding competition site - websearching for `lonelyinteger` brings lots of results. In the linked example, the other integers occur *twice*, so it's not exactly the same). Obviously, lots of important information had not been given, e.g. the limits of the *values* of the integers. If they are only in 1...100 (as in the linked question), then this is fairly trivial. Otherwise (if their range is arbitrary, up to 2^32), one might have to think twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is O(N^2) not considered "fast enough" for this problem?

Here I have a list of 10,000,000 elements with random pair values.  In a random spot, I put the "lonely integer" 5, and O(N^2) solves it quickly without the need to sort.  The algorithm stops on the first "lonely integer" it finds.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();

    List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i += 2) {
        int randomNumber = r.nextInt(100) + 10;
        ints.add(randomNumber);
        ints.add(randomNumber);
    }
    ints.add(5); // Lonely Integer

    int tempIndex = r.nextInt(ints.size());
    int tempValue = ints.get(tempIndex);
    // Swap duplicate integer with lonely integer
    ints.set(tempIndex, ints.get(ints.size() - 1)); 
    ints.set(ints.size() - 1, tempValue);

    for (int i = 0; i < ints.size(); i++) {
        boolean singleInteger = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < ints.size(); j++) {
            if (j == i) {
                continue;
            }
            if (ints.get(j) == ints.get(i)) {
                singleInteger = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (singleInteger) {
            System.out.println("Single instance: " + ints.get(i));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

> Single instance: 5 (about 10 - 20 seconds);

### Update

Your method about 3 seconds.

Map solution...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();

    List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i += 2) {
        int randomNumber = r.nextInt(100) + 10;
        ints.add(randomNumber);
        ints.add(randomNumber);
    }
    ints.add(5); // Lonely Integer
    int tempIndex = r.nextInt(ints.size());
    int tempValue = ints.get(tempIndex);
    // Swap duplicate integer with lonely integer
    ints.set(tempIndex, ints.get(ints.size() - 1));
    ints.set(ints.size() - 1, tempValue);

    Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i : ints) {
        if (counts.containsKey(i)) {
            counts.put(i, counts.get(i) + 1);
        } else {
            counts.put(i, 1);
        }
    }

    for (Integer key : counts.keySet()) {
        if (counts.get(key) == 1) {
            System.out.println("Single Instance: " + key);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

> Single Instance: 5 (about 1 - 3 seconds)

Comment: @sodium24 Yeah...  I retracted my update of finding multiple "lonely integers" after putting random pairs of numbers vs all the same number.  Afterwards I wanted to make sure that finding the first "lonely integer", inside of random pairs, still held up and it did.

Comment: sorry for the noob question I'm studying algorithms and I didn't really understand how to calculate time complexity but, 

I think my current solution has O(n*logn) complexity, isn't O(N^2) worse than that.

Comment: @waff Yes...  O(N * logN) is faster than O(N^2), but is your algorithm really O(N * logN), since you're calling Arrays.sort(a)?

Comment: Arrays.sort is a quick sort  method and it is O(n log(n)) on avarage. At least that's what google says. But again I'm no expert. http://bigocheatsheet.com/
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(byte[])

Comment: @waff Yes, I read that too, but then you're doing an O(n) search after O(N * logN) sort.  The two combined are still faster than O(n^2)?  I'm still learning O notation also.

Comment: I would say O(n*logn + n) is faster, if you look at the chart at cheat sheet graph O(n^2) is quite steep. http://bigocheatsheet.com/#chart

Comment: @waff You're right O(N*logN) + O(N) search is still much better than O(N^2).  I tried the Map method which looked to be faster.  See updates...

Comment: yes, it looks faster, but I don't understand I thought each contain search would go through all the array and it would be slower. anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you got the question right? The idea behind the lonely integer algorithm question, which is commonly posted on algorithm solving challenges, is that all numbers show up in pairs, except for one. From the sample that you used, it is not the case.

If all numbers are being displayed in pairs, except for one, the fastest way to find the solution is by applying XOR on all elements. Since XOR applied between two same elements cancels them, you will as a result have the lonely integer that you are looking for. The time complexity for this solution would be O(n).

Otherwise, if a number can be found in the given array more than two times, or you are using the solution you provided, the time complexity is O(n*logn).

Comment: the question is right. I'm simply asking if there's any way to improve the solution so it could work a bit faster than it is now.

Comment: Sorry for the misdirection, in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Start by checking that it's not `Arrays.sort(a);` that's taking too long for very large inputs.

If it's not the case, you could improve your method as follows

```
 static int lonelyinteger(int[] a) {
    if (a[0] != a[1]) return a[0];

    int i = 1;
    while ((i < a.length - 1) && (a[i] == a[i-1] || a[i] == a[i+1])) {
        i++;
    }

    if ((i < a.length -1) || (a[i] != a[i-1]))  return a[i];
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sort. then...

```
while (true) {
    if (a[0] != a[1]) {
        return a[i].
  } else {
      remove all a[0]s from a.
  }
}
```

this is O(nlogn).

an O(n) solution (one w/o sort) to find all the unique integers is to have a hash and run along the array. If the number does not appear in the hash, add the number to it. If it does appear in the hash, remove that number from the hash. At the end you'll have all the unique integers in one hash. boom.